# How to call methods of an external class in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a file under `/lib` with its own method.

```
# lib/file.rb
class File < ApplicationController
  def my_method
    ...
  end
end
```

However I can't reach the method through the console

```
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :044 > File.my_method
NoMethodError: undefined method `my_method' for File:Class
```

Any idea how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`my_method` is an instance method of the `File` class. It means that you can call it only on the instance of the `File` class.

```
file = File.new
file.my_method
```

You can declare `my_method` as class method using `def self.my_method` syntax.

```
class File < ApplicationController
  def self.my_method
    ...
  end
end

File.my_method
```

But in class methods you can't use instance variables of the `File` object.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `my_method` as a class method, but you've defined it as an instance method.

You should either define it as `def self.my_method`, or create an instance of the controller to call it as an instance method.

In addition, you are going to run into problems for a couple of reasons - (1) Rails expects controllers to be named like `FilesController`, and (2) `File` is a class in the standard library. I would encourage you to change the class name to `FilesController`, and rename the file itself to `files_controller.rb` to prevent both issues.

Answer (score 0):

Well... there are several interesting things going on with this example. The first would be that this class name is call `File` which is already defined in Ruby.

That is most likely why when you are in the console you didn't get an undefined class error. Since `my_method` is not defined on Ruby's `File` class, this is why you are seeing undefined method.

Now to your question. I would try naming your class something different first and trying again from `lib`. I believe it should be loaded by default again with the rails environment. For a version or two that functionality was taken out but I want to say it's back in. If not, just go into your `config/application.rb` file and look for a declaration along the lines of `config.autoload_paths`. Add the `lib` directory there and you should be good to go.

Lastly, is there a reason you want a controller in `lib`?