# how to call on a function from an outside rb file and assign the output of the function to a variable within the main rb file?

Tags: ruby

```
class DNATORNA
  def self.of_dna(dna)
    raise ArgumentError, 'Incorrect nucleotide' if dna.include? 'U'
    dna.tr('GCTA', 'CGAU')
  end
end
```

I want to use this code to obtain RNA sequence from DNA sequence in other file and proceed on working with RNA sequence.

Comment: Please read ruby documentation. This may help you though, if you know the basics. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643614/how-to-call-methods-of-an-external-class-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have an external file, let's say **car.rb**...

```
class Car
  def initialize(id, name)
    @id = id
    @name = name
  end

  def show_car
    puts "Car ##{@id}: #{@name}"
  end

  def get_name
    @name
  end
end
```

... you can call a function of that external file like this in your, let's say, **program.rb** if they are in the same folder...

```
require('./car')

c = Car.new(1, 'VW 1300')
c.show_car

car_name = c.get_name
puts car_name
```

... or like this if the file **car.rb** is in a **model** folder...

```
require('./model/car')

c = Car.new(1, 'VW 1300')
c.show_car

car_name = c.get_name
puts car_name
```

The last line of a ruby method is always equivalent to the *return operation*, even if you don't say it explicitely. Got it? :)